# Is it possible to display multiple datas in single field using listview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Iam fetching datas from two different mysql table and i want to display some column datas in single field while displaying using listview.How can i possible?

```
 <ItemTemplate>
<tr id="Tr2" runat="server" class="tablerw">
<td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;width:100px;" class="tablerw"> <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"
 Text='<%#Eval("DealName") %>' /></td>
 <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;width:100px;"> <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server"
 Text='<%#Eval("TicketNo") %>' /></td>

<td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;width:180px;"> <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"
          Text='<%#Eval("ItemName") %>' /></td>
 <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;width:180px;"> <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"
          Text='<%#Eval("Price") %>' /></td>
</tr>
```

Here is my item template,I have a deal name and ticket number and corresponding items(Items will have more than one).While display these contents using a listview,i need to show item details under a deal will be on single field.How can it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, `Eval` returns object, you can convert that to string and use `+` to concatenate both:-

```
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"
 Text='<%# Eval("DealName").ToString() + " " + Eval("TicketNo").ToString() %>' />
```